# Efficiently evaluating a polynomial with fixed constants with many values

Tags: polynomial-math, polynomials

I'm currently trying to evaluate a large polynomial (Degree ~10^5, the constants are the same for every input case) and find the values of the polynomial for many different values (I.e, evaluate the same polynomial and find the answer for a large number (~10^5) of values of x).

I tried using horner's method for evaluating every single input, but the program is too slow. Is there a way to optimize for many values?

Comment: I don't think you get around the computational effort as such, but you could make use of vectorization and apply the operation for multiple points at once. That is using an array of points and doing each multiplication and addition on arrays instead of scalars. Vectorization is an increasingly important hardware feature, you need to exploit for fast computations, and as you do many scalar*array operations in your setting you can also choose the array with a size that fits into your cache, which should give a pretty efficient code execution.

Comment: Taken from a live programming contest: https://www.codechef.com/JULY16/problems/POLYEVAL.  We're not here to solve your contest problems for you.  Please don't post problems taken from elsewhere without crediting/attributing the source.

Comment: @D.W. he didn't mention any of the constraints from that task, though...

Comment: @haraldkl, The question here says degree ~ 10^5, evaluate at ~ 10^5 points.  The live contest problem says degree is between 0 and 2.5 * 10^5, and number of points to evaluate at is between 0 and 2.5 * 10^5.  (See Constraints and Subtasks, Subtask #2 at that link.)  Coincidence?  You can decide for yourself.

Comment: @D.W. It definitely looks like it comes from there, just saying, with the question as stated here you can't expect to get a good answer for the more specific codechef problem ;)